# Unable to edit the reusable collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying something like this:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PostAttachmentCellView 
cell.backgroundImage.image = file as? UIImage
```

here collectionView has reusable cells of type `PostAttachmentCellView`.

However it throws an error of:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

the population is done in this way:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PACell", for: indexPath) as! PostAttachmentCellView
    cell.customize()

    return cell
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong here and how I should correct this. Help is much appreciated.

I don't want to just remove the error by putting it in `let` but I want the cell to have the background image too (as intuitive from the code).

Comment: what error , share it

Comment: @Sh_Khan, check again buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell is not `nil` only if it's visible

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PostAttachmentCellView {
   cell.backgroundImage.image = file as? UIImage
}
```

//

so you may edit the dataSource array of images and reload the table/cell

```
var images = [UIImage]()

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PACell", for: indexPath) as! PostAttachmentCellView
    cell.backgroundImage.image = images[indexPath.row]
    cell.customize()

    return cell
}
```

in your example you change image of first top cell so do this instead

```
 images[0] = file as? UIImage
 // here either reload the table/cell
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I want to have the collection view cell have the image. This just escapes the error.

Comment: you can't edit the image of a hidden cell as it's nil , alter the dataSource image and when that cell show it will be configured with latest changes

Comment: do you have only 2 images that a cell image can be setted to one at a time or every cell has an image ??

Comment: Every cell has an image.

Comment: I guess there is no need for the customize function? You could do all of the customization while you are at it.